# Obtain value of textblock inside in a Button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, mobile

I'm writting a Windows Phone App, in the GUI a have a listbox with many buttons, something like this

```
    <ListBox x:Name="List">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Width="460" Height="100" Click="Click_B">
                                    <Button.Content>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="80" Width="400">    
                                            <TextBlock Width="200" Name="txtblockName" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Name}" Height="40"/>
                                            <TextBlock Width="200" Name="txtblockUrl" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Url}" Height="40"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Button.Content>
                                </Button>                            
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I need to obtain the content of the TextBlock "txtblockUrl" when I click on the Button, how can I obtain this value ?

```
private void Click_B(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button source = (Button)e.OriginalSource;

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can walk down the layout hierarchy as shown below

```
private void Click_B(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  string s = ((((sender as Button).Content) as StackPanel).Children[1] as TextBlock).Text;
}
```

However, data binding a list of objects to your `ListBox.ItemsSource` is a better solution than this.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see things, is that you want to obtain the value of the `Name` property of the object bound to your button. You can find this object in your button's `DataContext` property.

If you replace `MyType` with the type of your bound object, something like this should do what you want:

```
private void Click_B(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button source = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
    string name = ((MyType)source.DataContext).Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There probably is a far better solution, but if you wanted to directly reference it, you could just cast your way down.

```
private void Click_B(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Button source = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
     StackPanel stp = source.Content as StackPanel;
     TextBlock blk = stp.Children[1];
     //Whatever you needed could now reference blk.Text
}
```

**EDIT: I would go with the data Binding solution above. This is just a quick and dirty way to access that TextBlock**